# sorting alpha numeric values in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary entries for the different users like below:

```
{'usr_1': '111', 'usr_2': '222','usr_22' : '3333', 
 'usr_8': '888','usr_11':'11111','usr_10':'10101'}
```

I want to sort this dictionary based on the key. The output should be

```
{'usr_1': '111', 'usr_2': '222','usr_8': '888',
'usr_10':'10101', 'usr_11':'11111','usr_22' : '3333'}
```

When I tried using the OrderedDict method it just returns changes the list to tuples and doesn't give me the sorted order I wanted.

```
dict1 = {'usr_1': '111', 'usr_2': '222','usr_22' : '3333', 
         'usr_8': '888','usr_11':'11111','usr_10':'10101'}

my_dict = OrderedDict(dict1)
print(my_dict)
```

**Output**

```
OrderedDict([('usr_1', '111'), ('usr_2', '222'), ('usr_22', '3333'),
             ('usr_8', '888'), ('usr_11', '11111'), ('usr_10', '10101')])
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Search for "Natural Sort", that should help you out.

Comment: `dict(sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].split("_", 1)[1])))`

Comment: Oh, and `OrderedDict` sorts by *insertion* order, not by key.

Comment: @MarkRansom I wouldn't call it "sorting" at all, but rather "keeping" insertion order. And not even that is correct, as its `move_to_end` method allows you to change the order without doing insertions.

Comment: It is bad practice, in my humble opinion, to rely on a dictionary being in any particular order.  It's similar to an SQL database, where the records are not ordered.  You don't need the records to be STORED in any particular order.  That makes no difference in operation, and just adds overhead.  What you need is to ACCESS them in a particular order.  That can be done by sorting the keys and iterating through the results of that sort, at the time you need to access them.  `for i in sorted(dct.keys(), compare=xxx):`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda that splits on "_" as key:

```
out = dict(sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda x: int(x[0].split('_')[1])))
```

Output:

```
{'usr_1': '111',
 'usr_2': '222',
 'usr_8': '888',
 'usr_10': '10101',
 'usr_11': '11111',
 'usr_22': '3333'}
```

Comment: Possible alternative is `dict(sorted(dict1.items(), key=lambda x: x[0][x[0].find("_") + 1:].zfill(3)))`

Answer (score 4):

In order to sort strings that contain numbers numerically, you can right-justify them to a common maximum length:

```
dict(sorted(dict1.items(),key="{0[0]:>20}".format))
```

output:

```
{'usr_1': '111', 'usr_2': '222', 'usr_8': '888', 'usr_10': '10101', 
 'usr_11': '11111', 'usr_22': '3333'}
```

*Note that this only works if the prefixing character is smaller than "0" (which "_" happens to be). If not, you would need to split the string or convert characters. (same goes if there are varying length non-digit prefixes)*

Comment: I guess it's a good thing that `' '` is the smallest "printable" character :-)